# How to upgrade the Jenkins in mac machine

Tags: plugins, jenkins, continuous-integration, updates

I have installed the jenkins in my mac machine through Mac Installer, my current jenkins version is 1.628 when I opens Manage Jenkins page it shown as below screen shot. I would like to update the jenkins to newer version 1.630, so can any one please suggest me how to upgrade?, If I upgrade is there any issue to my existing jenkins configuration and jobs? .[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **Step1**
  Click the download link to download the latest `jenkins.war` of version 1.630.
- **Step2**
  Replace the old `jenkins.war (version 1.628)` in your Mac to this new `jenkins.war (version 1.630)` and restart jenkins.

Comment: By replacing jenkins.war, can we sure we dont loss any jobs/configuration things? thanks

Comment: No worry about that. All the configurations and jobs under $JENKINS_HOME directory will be safe.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any way to check from terminal what is the current version of my jenkins running.

Comment: Even after replacing config.xml file shows jenkins version as previous version number only, but in jenkins web page am able to see latest version as installed. can you please suggest me to upgrade config.xml file aswell.